# What is this approach of iPhone Programming called?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have a sample code wherein:

- I am unable to understand how data flows from database to reports because there is no place to set or fetch data explicitly. It is all done through custom objects.
- Even we are not able to fetch data through console using NSLog as it has ENUM keys
- All objects are custom objects so if we put it in NSLogs we get structure like `< CustomObject-hexcode>`. Many of the classes again comprise of objects from other classes.
- Even if I try to debug code by putting breakpoint, then after few steps it show Hexadecimal codes

I wont be able to put sample code as it is a whole project containing lot of files.

Can you please let me know what kind of approach has been used? It looks like some sort of encapsulation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write categories that implement the `- (NSString* ) description` method for each custom object that displays all variables the custom obejects hold, you can there translate each of the enum values to strings.  Then you can use NSLog to output objects and get readable results.

Comment: I think you mean `- (NSString *)description`

Comment: Thanks for the input.  Actually under the custom classes, I am not able to see any of the variables of known datatype as per objective-C. Many of the classes again comprise of objects from other classes. So in that case, what could be done?

Comment: @john:  Yes I did, fixed.  @PARTH: If just print out what is accessible (use all the accessor methods and translate any results as needed).

Answer (score 0):

you need to debug application. and for this "All objects are custom objects so if we put it in NSLogs we get structure like < CustomObject-hexcode>"
you need to integrate a category class in your project. Search on google for override description of nsobject. You will get nslog in proper format.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Can you please provide a sample link for putting NSLogs in proper format?

Comment: @Parth you need to override description method of the your custom object class. Each class which is inherited from nsobject have the method named description. you need to override that method. here is a link for you to better understand http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/overriding-nsobject-description-method.html

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like some kind of custom ORM with serialization / deserialization etc. Euuuwww.